# How can I remove the first line of a file with sed?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

the following lines append the content of essay_i.txt to the end of essay1.txt;

```
touch essay1.txt
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ )); do
sed '2p' essay_"${i}".txt >> essay1.txt
done
```

how should i change it so that the first line of each of essay_i.txt are not copied (i.e. only copy line 2->end) ?

Comment: Is it the appending you want, or the sed version?  For straight shell, you could use ` tail -n +2 essay_i.txt >> essay1.txt `

Comment: Your script copies the seconds line twice, is that intentional? (actually, it doesn't work at all for me, so I'm guessing)

Comment: @ Stefano Palazzo: sorry my bad (typping error). Thanks.

Comment: You can do it without the loop too: `awk 'FNR>1' essay_[0-9].txt essay_[1-9][0-9].txt > essay1.txt`. Would be even shorter if the numbers in the filenames were zero-padded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To suppress the first line, use `'1d'` (i.e. line 1, delete):

```
touch essay1.txt
for file in essay_*; do
  sed '1d' $file >> essay1.txt
done
```

the output will be

```
~$ cat essay1.txt 
line 2 from essay 1
line 3 from essay 1
line 2 from essay 2
line 3 from essay 2
...
```

for all of the files named `essay_*` in the current working directory.

---

Instead of using `sed`, you can also use `tail` to do this job:

```
tail -n +2 $file >> essay1.txt
```

Where `+2` means from the second line onwards (`-n 2` would be the last two lines).