# Which is faster to delete first line in file... sed or tail?

Tags: scripts, sed, tail

In this answer ([How can I remove the first line of a file with sed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25174/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-file-with-sed/25177#25177)) there are two ways to delete the first record in a file:

```
sed '1d' $file >> headerless.txt
```

** ----------------  OR ----------------**

```
tail -n +2 $file >> headerless.txt
```

Personally I think the `tail` option is cosmetically more pleasing and more readable but probably because I'm sed-challenged.

Which method is fastest?

Comment: Not an answer, but a possible consideration is that `sed` is more portable: "+2" for `tail` works fine on Ubuntu, which uses GNU `tail`, but won't work on BSD `tail`.

Comment: @JohnN thanks for sharing `tail` lack of cross-platform compatability.

Comment: @John N "+2" for tail works fine on may Mac running Sierra which claims to use the BSD tail command

Comment: Urgh, you're quite right - I've just re-run it and this time checked the input. Which I should have done the first time. It's POSIX, too. /slinks off, embarrased.

Comment: @JohnN look at the bright side you got 4 good comment flags for an incorrect comment...LOL

Comment: @JohnN You're not completely wrong. In the past, UNIX didn't provide the `-n` option, and used the syntax `tail +2 $file`. See https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tail&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition&arch=default&format=html It's possible you were thinking of that rather than one of the modern BSDs.

Comment: Interesting that you think the `tail` one is more readable, I find the `sed` one more understandable, and a more direct translation of the desired behavior (`d`elete `1`)

Comment: @Kevin It's just that I've used `tail` before but haven't used `sed` unless  copying someone else's instructions.

Comment: I think it's worth learning sed, it's really quite powerful.

Comment: @Kevin Agreed... Indeed you could say I just learned a little more about it in the last 10 minutes thanks to your comment :)

Comment: There's also `awk 'NR > 1'`. But unless you're working on gigabyte+ files and speed is demonstrably a problem, it's really moot. And if it is a real problem, you should profile options on your setup and data set anyway.

Comment: @Kevin You can post `awk` as an answer. The fastest way would be to change the files starting address to the byte after first CR/LF and reduce file's size by *Old Starting Address* - *New Starting Address*. Not sure how the OS would like that though... Especially bad if files have to start on specific 512 byte boundaries.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Performance of `sed` vs. `tail` to remove the first line of a file

## TL;DR

- `sed` is very powerful and versatile, but this is what makes it slow, especially for large files with many lines.
- `tail` does just one simple thing, but that one it does well and fast, even for bigger files with many lines.

For small and medium sized files, `sed` and `tail` are performing similarly fast (or slow, depending on your expectations). However, for larger input files (multiple MBs), the performance difference grows significantly (an order of magnitude for files in the range of hundreds of MBs), with `tail` clearly outperforming `sed`.

## Experiment

### General Preparations:

Our commands to analyze are:

```
sed '1d' testfile > /dev/null
tail -n +2 testfile > /dev/null
```

Note that I'm piping the output to `/dev/null` each time to eliminate the terminal output or file writes as performance bottleneck.

Let's set up a RAM disk to eliminate disk I/O as potential bottleneck. I personally have a `tmpfs` mounted at `/tmp` so I simply placed my `testfile` there for this experiment.

Then I am once creating a random test file containing a specified amount of lines `$numoflines` with random line length and random data using this command (note that it's definitely not optimal, it becomes really slow for about >2M lines, but who cares, it's not the thing we're analyzing):

```
cat /dev/urandom | base64 -w0 | tr 'n' '\n'| head -n "$numoflines" > testfile
```

Oh, btw. my test laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit on an Intel i5-6200U CPU. Just for comparison.

### Timing big files:

#### Setting up a huge `testfile`:

Running the command above with `numoflines=10000000` produced a random file containing 10M lines, occupying a bit over 600 MB - it's quite huge, but let's start with it, because we can:

```
$ wc -l testfile 
10000000 testfile

$ du -h testfile 
611M    testfile

$ head -n 3 testfile 
qOWrzWppWJxx0e59o2uuvkrfjQbzos8Z0RWcCQPMGFPueRKqoy1mpgjHcSgtsRXLrZ8S4CU8w6O6pxkKa3JbJD7QNyiHb4o95TSKkdTBYs8uUOCRKPu6BbvG
NklpTCRzUgZK
O/lcQwmJXl1CGr5vQAbpM7TRNkx6XusYrO
```

#### Perform the timed run with our huge `testfile`:

Now let's do just a single timed run with both commands first to estimate with what magnitudes we're working.

```
$ time sed '1d' testfile > /dev/null
real    0m2.104s
user    0m1.944s
sys     0m0.156s

$ time tail -n +2 testfile > /dev/null
real    0m0.181s
user    0m0.044s
sys     0m0.132s
```

We already see a really clear result for big files, `tail` is a magnitude faster than `sed`. But just for fun and to be sure there are no random side effects making a big difference, let's do it 100 times:

```
$ time for i in {1..100}; do sed '1d' testfile > /dev/null; done
real    3m36.756s
user    3m19.756s
sys     0m15.792s

$ time for i in {1..100}; do tail -n +2 testfile > /dev/null; done
real    0m14.573s
user    0m1.876s
sys     0m12.420s
```

The conclusion stays the same, `sed` is inefficient to remove the first line of a big file, `tail` should be used there.

And yes, I know Bash's loop constructs are slow, but we're only doing relatively few iterations here and the time a plain loop takes is not significant compared to the `sed`/`tail` runtimes anyway.

### Timing small files:

#### Setting up a small `testfile`:

Now for completeness, let's look at the more common case that you have a small input file in the kB range. Let's create a random input file with `numoflines=100`, looking like this:

```
$ wc -l testfile 
100 testfile

$ du -h testfile 
8,0K    testfile

$ head -n 3 testfile 
tYMWxhi7GqV0DjWd
pemd0y3NgfBK4G4ho/
aItY/8crld2tZvsU5ly
```

#### Perform the timed run with our small `testfile`:

As we can expect the timings for such small files to be in the range of a few milliseconds from experience, let's just do 1000 iterations right away:

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do sed '1d' testfile > /dev/null; done
real    0m7.811s
user    0m0.412s
sys     0m7.020s

$ time for i in {1..1000}; do tail -n +2 testfile > /dev/null; done
real    0m7.485s
user    0m0.292s
sys     0m6.020s
```

As you can see, the timings are quite similar, there's not much to interpret or wonder about. For small files, both tools are equally well suited.

Comment: +1 for answering thank you. I edited the original question (sorry) based upon comment from Serg that `awk` can do this too. My original question was based on the link I found in the first place. After all your hard work please advise if I should remove `awk` as a solution candidate and return focus to original project scope of only `sed` and `tail`.

Comment: What system is this? On my mac (so BSD tools), testing on /usr/share/dict/words gives me 0.09s for sed and 0.19s for tail (and `awk 'NR > 1'`, interestingly).

Answer (score 5):

Here's another alternative, using just bash builtins and `cat`:

```bash
{ read ; cat > headerless.txt; } < $file
```

`$file` is redirected into the `{ }` command grouping.  The `read` simply reads and discards the first line.  The rest of the stream is then piped to `cat` which writes it to the destination file.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 the performance of this and the `tail` solution are very similar.  I created a largish test file with `seq`:

```bash
$ seq 100000000 > 100M.txt
$ ls -l 100M.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 888888898 Dec 20 17:04 100M.txt
$
```

#### `tail` solution:

```bash
$ time tail -n +2 100M.txt > headerless.txt

real    0m1.469s
user    0m0.052s
sys 0m0.784s
$
```

#### `cat`/brace solution:

```bash
$ time { read ; cat > headerless.txt; } < 100M.txt 

real    0m1.877s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.736s
$
```

I only have an Ubuntu VM handy right now though, and saw significant variation in the timings of both, though they're all in the same ballpark.

Comment: +1 for answer thank you. That's a very interesting solution and I love the braces and right to left reading via bash's hierarchy order. (not sure if I worded that correctly). Is it possible to update your answer with size of input file and timing benchmark results if that's easy enough to do?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Timings added, though they're not very reliable as this is on a VM.  I don't have a bare-metal Ubuntu installation handy right now.

Comment: I don't think VM vs Bare Metal matters when you are comparing VM to VM anyway. Thanks for the timing proof. I'd probably go with `tail` but still think the `read` option is very cool.

Answer (score 4):

Trying in on my system, and prefixing each command with `time` I got the following results:

sed:

```
real    0m0.129s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and tail:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

which suggest that, on my system at least AMD FX 8250 running Ubuntu 16.04, tail is significantly faster. The test file had 10,000 lines with a size of 540k. The file was read from a HDD.

Comment: +1 for answering thank you.  In a separate test in AU Chatroom one user showed tail is 10 times faster (2.31 seconds) than sed (21.86 seconds) using a RAMDisk with 61 MB file. I did edit your answer to apply code blocks but you might want to edit it too with the file size you used.

Comment: @Serg Absolutely fair that this is only an anecdotal answer, and potentially you would get different results with different hardware configurations, different test files etc.

Comment: The file not being in cache, when using `sed` might play a factor in this result, that's the order you have tested them in.

Comment: what sort of system? As I commented on another post here, on my mac `sed` was about twice as fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no objective way to say which is better, because `sed` and `tail` aren't the only things that run on a system during program execution. A lot of factors such as disk i/o, network i/o, CPU interrupts for higher priority processes - all those influence how fast your program will run.

Both of them are written in C, so this is not language issue, but more of environmental one. For example, I have SSD and on my system this will take time in microseconds, but for same file on hard drive it will take more time because HDDs are significantly slower. So hardware plays role in this,too.

There's a few things that you may want to keep in mind when considering which command to choose:

- What is your purpose ? `sed` is stream editor for transforming text. `tail` is for outputting specific lines of text. If you want to deal with lines  and only print them out , use `tail`. If you want to edit the text, use `sed`.
- `tail` has far simpler syntax than `sed`, so use what you can read yourself and what others can read.

---

Another important factor is the amount of data you're processing. Small files won't give you any performance difference. The picture gets interesting when you're dealing with big files.  With a 2 GB BIGFILE.txt, we can see that `sed` has far more system calls than `tail`, and runs considerably slower.

```
bash-4.3$ du -sh BIGFILE.txt 
2.0G    BIGFILE.txt
bash-4.3$ strace -c  sed '1d' ./BIGFILE.txt  > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 59.38    0.079781           0    517051           read
 40.62    0.054570           0    517042           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        10         1 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           close
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        19           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        12           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         7         7 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         2 statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.134351               1034177        11 total
bash-4.3$ strace -c  tail  -n +2 ./BIGFILE.txt  > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 62.30    0.148821           0    517042           write
 37.70    0.090044           0    258525           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         9         3 open
  0.00    0.000000           0         8           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         7           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         3 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.238865                775615         7 total
```

Comment: +1 for answering thank you. But I'm not sure this comment is helping me decide which command I should use....

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix   Well, you asked which command is better, so i am answering exactly that question. Which command to choose, is up to you. If you can read `tail` better than `sed` - use that. I personally would use `python` or `awk` rather than `sed` because it can get complex. Besides, if you are concerned about performance, let's face the reality - you are seeing results in microseconds here.  You won't feel difference unless it's a freakin huge file in range of gigabytes that you're trying to read

Comment: Oh I would appreciate an `awk` answer too :)... My question was based on another AU Q&A (in the link) and there they never mentioned `awk`. I agree the time difference is nominal on small files. I was just trying to develop some good habits.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Sure, here it is : `awk 'NR!=1' input_file.txt `. It gives me equally same result , around 150  milliseconds , same number for both `tail` and `sed`. But agian, I am using SSD, so  i'd say it's the hard drive and CPU that matter, not the command.

Comment: The `awk` version looks the best (most readable). There is no output file and does it in place? Also if you run awk, sed and tail on the same file should consideration be given the kernel may have cached/buffered some of the file stuff in RAM?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You still need output file. Use `> new_file.txt` to redirect.  Only `sed` has in-place editing and GNU awk, if I'm not mistaken.   There's many `awk` variations, but just use redirection to be consistent and portable. As for kernel caching, I don't know - that's probably deserves a whole different question.

Comment: @Serg even with only a 60 MB file containing 1M lines, 1000 runs with `sed` take far over 3 minutes, whereas `tail` only needs around 20 seconds. That is not *that* big yet actually, definitely not in the GB range.

Comment: @ByteCommander Well, aside from the fact that you're looping with `bash` , which itself is slow, in my test it gave for tail 47 seconds for `tail` and 12 minutes for `sed`. Again, I don't think looping is a good test, because you're running a command 1000 times, you're not processing one big  file.

Comment: But even with Bash loops being slow, they'Re not *that* slow. According to [your link from chat](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303167/103151), a Bash `for` loop iteration takes some time in the order of magnitude of 10 µs. For 1000 iterations, this adds up to 10 ms. The total times we're measuring are in the order of magnitude of tens of seconds to minutes - I consider Bash loop performance loss insignificant here.

Comment: @Serg it's not true that just because other things can happen at the same time, there's no objective way to tell which is better. If that were true, [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack), which must deal with the same sorts of noise you mention, would be unobjective, yet they aren't. There are ways to minimize the impact of noise and to increase the signal strength. One of the major uses of statistics is figuring out objectively what contributes to some effect in spite of noise.

Answer (score 1):

Top answer didn't take disk into account doing `> /dev/null`

if you have a large file and don't want to create a temporary duplicate on your disk try `vim -c`

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | base64 -w0 | tr 'n' '\n'| head -n 10000000 > testfile
$ time sed -i '1d' testfile

real    0m59.053s
user    0m9.625s
sys     0m48.952s

$ cat /dev/urandom | base64 -w0 | tr 'n' '\n'| head -n 10000000 > testfile
$ time vim -e -s testfile -c ':1d' -c ':wq'

real    0m8.259s
user    0m3.640s
sys     0m3.093s
```

Edit: if the file is larger than available memory `vim -c` doesn't work, looks like its not smart enough to do an incremental load of the file

Answer (score 0):

Other answers show well what is better to create a new file with first line missing. If you want to edit a file as opposed to create a new file though, I bet `ed` would be faster because it shouldn't create a new file at all. But you have to search how to remove a line with `ed` because I used it only once.